# Parse Export Data to csv, xls etc

Tags: mysql, csv, parse-platform, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I'm currently in the process of trying to export a Parse app into a MySql database. The tables have a similar setup, so to make the process quicker I was wondering if anyone has figured out an easy to way to export Parse data as a file format the phpmyadmin was accept for importing data (csv, xls, etc.).

I know Parse exports to Json, and I have found several posts around exporting to other file formats, but most are fairly old (a few years atleast), so I was just wondering if anyone had found a way to do this since?

Comment: have a look at this if you don't find a more direct way. http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/

Comment: Quite a handy little solution actually!

Comment: I'm sure there is a library to automate this, too...

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? The only JSON to CSV convertors can't handle how much data I need converted...